# Do any Hindu schools of thought ascribe to the efficacy of prayer wheels?

Tags: tantra, buddhism

[Prayer wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_wheel) are commonplace in Tibetan Buddhism. According to their lineage texts regarding prayer wheels, spinning such a wheel will have much the same meritorious effect as orally reciting the prayers. Is there any equivalent in any Hindu school of thought?

Comment: Sounds like a cultural thing from erstwhile china and tibet, not original to Buddhism?

Comment: no, it is Buddhist.